# Not Getting Own Birthdate from Facebook

Tags: ios, swift, facebook

I have done lots of R&D to getting private birthday from `facebook`, but not able to get private birthday.

I have given birthday permission in code. Also tried to delete app from user's account but no luck.

```
if((FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken()) != nil){
    FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields": "id, birthday, name, first_name, last_name, picture.type(large), email, gender"]).startWithCompletionHandler({ (connection, result, error) -> Void in
         if (error == nil){
             Print("Success")
         }else{
             Print("Failed")
         }
  })    
}else{
    Print("Device token is Nil")
}
```

Please Help me out where is my mistake.

Comment: Try the account in which you have registered your app. If you have not submitted you app for review.

Comment: debug the token and make sure user_birthday is authorized

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> To access birthdate from facebook, You need to request for
>   **user_birthday** permission and submit you app for facebook review. If
>   facebook will approve this permission, then you can get birthdate.
>   meanwhile you can test using the account in which you have registered
>   your app.
>
> Go through
>   https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions#reference-user_birthday

[image]